# Donde usar la funcion Def

Tags: python

tenía pensado hacer como una pequeña lotería en Python. Y bueno no se me ocurre donde puedo "colocar" la función Def, es decir, en que parte del código tendría que usar la función def, siento no ser tan específico. Gracias de antemano. Mi código es el siguiente:

Dejo un pastebin con el código porque no puedo escribir tanto códígo por aquí

[Pastebin del código](https://pastebin.com/raw/72xsj2Ja)

Comment: si no. te deja publicar tanto código es por algo... redúcelo a algo que sea [mcve] y ponlo en la propia pregunta. Intenta sé más especifico en la pregunta, así será más probable que recibas respuestas

Comment: `def` no es una función; se usa para definir funciones, tal como `def log(x)`

Answer (score 1):

**Como usar el `def`**

El código en cuestión es una larga lista de más de 300 instrucciones. El programa no es complejo y está decentemente escrito. Sin embargo, se puede mejorar enormemente usando `def`.

La receta es simple: mira tu código e identifica un trozo que haga algo bien definido. Por ejemplo, este trozo pide una lista de cinco numeros:

```
#PASO 02 PIDE NUMEROS
 
listaNumero = []
numNumero=0
while (numNumero<5):
    
    numeroNumero=int(input("Introduce un número: "))
    
    if numeroNumero > 50:
        print("ERROR")
        print ("Introduce un número del boleto  menor o igual a 50: ")
        
    else:   
         if numeroNumero in listaNumero:
                print ("Este número ya existe")
         else:
             listaNumero+=[numeroNumero]
             numNumero=numNumero+1
    print(listaNumero)
```

Por tanto, puedo transformarlo en una función con parámetros valor máximo y cantidad de números deseados. La función pedira y validará los números, retornando la lista:

```
def pide_numeros(valor_maximo, num_elementos) :
    listaNumero = []
    numNumero=0
    while (numNumero < num_elementos):
        
        numeroNumero=int(input("Introduce un número: "))
        
        if numeroNumero > valor_maximo:
            print("ERROR")
            print (f"Introduce un número del boleto  menor o igual a {valor_maximo}: ")
            
        else:   
             if numeroNumero in listaNumero:
                    print ("Este número ya existe")
             else:
                 listaNumero+=[numeroNumero]
                 numNumero=numNumero+1

    return listaNumero
```

Fijate que elimine el `print` de la lista de números. La idea es separar la obtención del número de su uso.

Si aplicas el mismo principio al resto del código, terminaras con ... no sé ... una docena de funciones, y tu programa principal se limitara a llamarlas en secuencia:

```
pintar_boleto()
numeros = pide_numeros(50, 5)
estrellas = pide_estrellas()
sortear()
revisar_aciertos()
```

Al ir definiendo funciones también podrás eliminar código repetido y encontrar oportunidades para simplificar el código restante.

Usar funciones te permite crear programas de cualquier complejidad.